# combine 2 sql select count statements

Tags: sql, jet

I ahave 2 simple count queries:

```
select count (*) from t_object
select count (*) from t_diagram
```

How is the simplest way to combine their result (sum)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get two different count:

```
select count (*), 't_object count' from t_object
union all
select count (*), 't_diagram count' from t_diagram
```

To get the sum of the counts, use a derived table:

```
select sum(dt.cnt) from
(
 select count(*) as cnt from t_object
 union all
 select count(*) as cnt from t_diagram
) dt
```

Or, use a sub-query:

```
select count(*) + (select count(*) from t_diagram) from t_object
```

Comment: This would return an unordered rowset with two rows containing two numbers. You wouldn't be able to tell which was which.

Comment: @jarlh, Thanks. I would like to get sum.

Comment: Now edited, result now includes info on which count.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "combine".  To sum them up:

```
select  (select count (*) from t_object) + count(*) as combined_count
from    t_diagram
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error: `The select statement includes a ersversed word or an argument name that misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.` Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need at least one source table. Jarlh's answer already had that btw.